# Resolve Laravel library and model name crash

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, namespaces

I have a library and a model with the same class name. How do I instantiate the model in my library class?

/application/libraries/property/request.php

```
<?php namespace Property;

class Request {
...
```

/application/models/request.php

```
<?php 

class Request extends Eloquent {
...
```

In need to instantiate the model in Request library. `new \Models\Request()` will result in "Class 'Models\Request' not found".

Is there anyway to resolve this issue without changing class name?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `new Request()`, or `new \Request()`? I'm not sure but your `Request` model isn't defined in the `Models` namespace, so that could be it …

Comment: `new Request()` in the "/application/libraries/property/request.php" will only instantiate the Request library class, not the model. `new \Request()` does not work either.

I have tried adding "namespace Models;" in "/application/models/request.php" but I have not been able to find a way to instantiate the Request model class.

Comment: Hm, strange, sorry that didn't help. I don't think it's ideal to have a Request controller and a Request model, so maybe try renaming the controller to RequestConroller ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to namespace your Request class so other files know where in the namespace it is, otherwise there's no way to know if it's in \, \Models, \Property, or whatnot.

You should really have this:

/application/libraries/property/request.php

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries\Property;

class Request {
...
```

/application/models/request.php

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class Request extends Eloquent {
...
```

Then in your request library: `use App\Models\Request as RequestModel;` (not sure if you can keep it the same name).